# Which relationship line to use in a UML class diagram?

Tags: uml, diagram, relationship, class-diagram, relationships

In a UML class diagram I want to show the relationship between two classes where the second class is the type of a class variable in the first.

I've looked [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Relationships) but am still unsure which relationship I should be using.

I think it may be the **Dependency** relationship but I am unsure.

Which should I be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a [composition(has a)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition)  but would need to hear more about your diagram.

Comment: Ahh this sound more like it, as my NearestNeighbourSearch has a DistanceFunction